# JS - Making a Login page using an XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, xml, request, xmlhttprequest

I am attempting to create a login page on my mini site that allows users to download material. I am struggling with the xhr request, in order to check if the password and username are valid. Is the following code sufficient in what I am trying to do? Any help would be appreciated.

```
function login() {
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
const uri = "localhost"; // uri for request inserted here
xhr.open("GET", uri, true, Username, Password);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.onload= function() {
    const resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    document.getElementById("Login").innerHTML = resp;
}
xhr.send(null)  
}
```

Comment: User authentication is not trivial. Question is far too broad as outlined in the [help]

Answer (score 0):

Although it is your personal wish but one should never check username and password validity using xhr. These should always be done with form submissions. And the next thing is that it is never safe to use GET in requests for fields such as passwords. Always use passwords.
You need to edit your code.